# How to allow users to view and edit only their corresponding row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I have a Google Sheet with a list of rows. I would like to invite other users and allow them to **view and edit only their row**. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: Hi @pnuts At your suggestion, I researched a little more and I realize I had been careless while reading the question and I apologize. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: It is possible to restrict access to **Editing** a range, but not viewing.

Comment: @pnuts There will be many users so it's tedious to do.

Comment: @Ray Right, I tested it and didn't know how to restrict viewing.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. Looks like it's not possible yet. Will test with Google Forms.